# Projecting non-central Gaussian on a sphere?

Tags: probability-distributions, spherical-coordinates

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and covariance matrix $\sigma^2I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix.

If I **condition** on the distribution lying on the unit sphere and if $|\mu|=1$, I am told that the resulting probability distribution is the [von Mises-Fisher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution).

My question is: if I **project** the Gaussian onto the sphere, what is the resulting distribution?  Does it have a name?